# Generic function to return all files of some file-extensions of a directory

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to make a generic function to list and return all the files of some extensions inside a directory.

I know how to do this but the issue is I hope maybe exist a better and efficient method to filter the files instead iterating them with a For.

basically what I need is to convert this line of code into a generic function:

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*").Where(Function(s) s.EndsWith(".exe") OrElse s.EndsWith(".xml"))
```

something like this (the code does not work):

```
dim files = Files("C:\", {"jpg", "mp3"})
private function Get_Files(byval directory as string, byval Extensions() as string)
    return Directory.GetFiles(directory , "*").Where(Function(s) s.EndsWith(Extensions))
end sub
```

...Or a better way if any (without a For or any other large loopings).

Comment: Sometimes this is called "file globbing," e.g. on Unix systems. Maybe a search for that would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with a return of FileInfo objects. They contain more info about your files.

```
Private Function GetFileInfos(dir As String, ParamArray exts() As String) As List(Of FileInfo)
  Return New DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles.Where(Function(o) exts.Contains(o.Extension)).ToList
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou so much works perfect! I can't vote your answer 'cause I need 15 rep to vote up but the answer is great! thanks.